# How to test inline installation of Chromium/Chrome extensions locally?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to test the inline installation feature of the Chrome Webstore as per this document (https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation).
I am developing this locally to test and cannot easily and often push my changes live.

How do I test inline installation locally since inline installation depends on your site being verified in Webmaster Tools?

**Code**

```
if (!chrome.app.isInstalled) {
    chrome.webstore.install(undefined, undefined, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

This returns:

```
Installs can only be initiated by the Chrome Web Store item's verified site
```

Obviously localhost is not a verified site.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From [Google's Using Inline Installation guide](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation): "Note that if you verify ownership for a domain (for example, http://example.com) you can initiate inline installation from any subdomain or page".

So, if you do own a domain, you can verify it and then simulate that your local machine is a subdomain of your verified domain.

For instance, if you verify with Google the domain example.com, you can include the following in your hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 local.example.com
```

Then you can access your local server via http://local.example.com (some configuration on your local webserver may be needed). If you associate your item in the Chrome Webstore with example.com, you'll be able to start an inline installation from your local page.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. My domain `local.myspecialdomain.com` still redirects to `myspecialdomain.com` instead of redirecting to `localhost` which is what i want it to do.

Comment: Are you using Windows? Did you changed your hosts file? It's located on: c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc

Comment: Chrome doesn't take into consideration the host file anymore, AFAIK it's impossible to force chrome to use your local host file on ANY OS

Comment: @mahieddine This is false (at least on Linux). Chromium and Chrome both follow the directives in /etc/hosts.

Comment: Well, I suppose it doesn't work anymore, at least for current date. I have my domain added in list of verified websites, I configurated hosts file and the proxy (so my domain is now proxying to the localhost), by I still get an error ```Installs can only be initiated by one of the Chrome Web Store item's verified sites.```

Comment: @MikeBaranczak chrome performs its own DNS lookups through its own DNS servers https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117655 sure there are hacks to get around this behaviour based on your OS and what you are trying to do but the default behaviour is this