# Chrome Inline Installation Testing without verifying the domain?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

How to test Chrome Inline Installation in an Corporate Internal Dev Environment?

Chrome Inline Installation requires the site to be verified. **Verifying the whole domain is NOT feasible** in my case, so I need some other ideas. Otherwise, end-to-end testing would be a nightmare because you always need to push it to production site to verify inline installation related changes.

Comment: See my answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908413

Comment: @rsanchez This is similar, but this is not a dup of the question. In my situation, I can't verify my domain for various reasons.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?